# How to get NN to give just 0 and 1 as output

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, neural-network

I am using pytorch and trying to train a neural network to find the difference between the local maximum and minimum on the graph. Right now i just want to get 1 if the spike is detected in the batch or 0 if not.

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

To do this, I have collected a lot of data reflecting these situations. The input data is simply the x,y coordinates, and the output is 1 if the spike is detected in the batch or 0 if not, as well as x which is the middle of such a segment. All the data is split into the batches of 64 except of the output which is just formatted as one x coordinate and one y coordinate per batch.

What is the optimal NN model that can return me just x coordinate and 1 if the spike is detected or 0 if not.

Right now my neural network gives the following results (blue is the data I fed it and at the bottom are red bars of prediction):

[image: Red dots at the bottom are supposed to show where spikes are]

Red bars close up:

[image: Red bars]

Now i'm using the following model:

```
class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(64, 60)
        self.act1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(60, 60)
        self.act2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.output = nn.Linear(60, 1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()
 
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.act1(self.layer1(x))
        x = self.act2(self.layer2(x))
        x = self.sigmoid(self.output(x))
        return x
```

And the following optimizer and loss function:

```
criterion = nn.BCELoss()  # Binary Cross Entropy Loss for binary classification
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
```

Data example:

```
 tensor([[0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488,
             0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0488,
             0.0488, 0.0488, 0.0489, 0.0489, 0.0489, 0.0489, 0.0489, 0.0489, 0.0490,
             0.0490, 0.0490, 0.0490, 0.0490, 0.0490, 0.0490, 0.0490, 0.0490, 0.0491,
             0.0491, 0.0491, 0.0491, 0.0491, 0.0491, 0.0491, 0.0492, 0.0492, 0.0492,
             0.0492, 0.0492, 0.0492, 0.0492, 0.0492, 0.0492, 0.0492, 0.0493, 0.0493,
             0.0493, 0.0493, 0.0494, 0.0494, 0.0494, 0.0494, 0.0495, 0.0495, 0.0495,
             0.0495],
            [0.9457, 0.9466, 0.9475, 0.9518, 0.9527, 0.9554, 0.9554, 0.9580, 0.9580,
             0.9580, 0.9589, 0.9606, 0.9615, 0.9615, 0.9597, 0.9580, 0.9518, 0.9518,
             0.9554, 0.9676, 0.9580, 0.9431, 0.9396, 0.9431, 0.9466, 0.9518, 0.9501,
             0.9378, 0.9370, 0.9378, 0.9378, 0.9378, 0.9387, 0.9405, 0.9405, 0.9378,
             0.9378, 0.9378, 0.9396, 0.9405, 0.9405, 0.9405, 0.9343, 0.9343, 0.9317,
             0.9308, 0.9282, 0.9370, 0.9265, 0.9256, 0.9256, 0.9177, 0.9230, 0.9230,
             0.9405, 0.9291, 0.9230, 0.9317, 0.9238, 0.9238, 0.9221, 0.9177, 0.9177,
             0.9177]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)
    tensor([[0.0488],
            [1]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)
    tensor([[0.1719, 0.1719, 0.1720, 0.1720, 0.1720, 0.1720, 0.1720, 0.1720, 0.1720,
             0.1720, 0.1720, 0.1720, 0.1720, 0.1720, 0.1720, 0.1720, 0.1720, 0.1721,
             0.1721, 0.1721, 0.1721, 0.1721, 0.1721, 0.1722, 0.1722, 0.1722, 0.1722,
             0.1722, 0.1722, 0.1723, 0.1723, 0.1723, 0.1723, 0.1723, 0.1724, 0.1724,
             0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725,
             0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1725, 0.1726,
             0.1726, 0.1726, 0.1726, 0.1726, 0.1726, 0.1726, 0.1727, 0.1727, 0.1727,
             0.1727],
            [0.9939, 0.9939, 0.9947, 0.9947, 0.9974, 0.9974, 0.9974, 0.9974, 0.9974,
             0.9974, 0.9974, 0.9974, 0.9974, 0.9974, 0.9974, 1.0000, 0.9851, 0.9842,
             0.9877, 0.9877, 0.9755, 0.9790, 0.9790, 0.9790, 0.9755, 0.9764, 0.9807,
             0.9816, 0.9816, 0.9685, 0.9755, 0.9737, 0.9667, 0.9702, 0.9615, 0.9659,
             0.9580, 0.9580, 0.9580, 0.9580, 0.9580, 0.9580, 0.9580, 0.9606, 0.9720,
             0.9729, 0.9755, 0.9764, 0.9781, 0.9790, 0.9790, 0.9764, 0.9632, 0.9615,
             0.9615, 0.9615, 0.9554, 0.9562, 0.9571, 0.9606, 0.9606, 0.9606, 0.9606,
             0.9615]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)
    tensor([[0.1715],
            [1]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)
```

I tried training it for as long as 100000 epochs it still showed unsatisfying result.

Link for the training files: [link](https://file.io/2xV9yZuYpcpx)

What am I supposed to change in the model so it gives exactly 0 or 1 as an output?

Comment: So you basically want a binary classifier on a function that outputs 1 when and only if there is a positive spike? My first comment is that using a dense NN for this is definitely overkill. Anyways what the model is outputting is its CONFIDENCE that it is observing a spike, so you should set a THRESHOLD value to decide: 
see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/96690/how-to-choose-the-right-threshold-for-binary-classification and https://machinelearningmastery.com/building-a-binary-classification-model-in-pytorch/

Comment: "Right now i just want to get 1 if the spike is detected in the batch or 0 if not."  or  "What is the optimal NN model that can return me just x coordinate and 1 if the spike is detected or 0 if not."  Which is it?

Comment: "I have collected a lot of data reflecting these situations."  How much?

Comment: What's your definition of a spike? Is there some threshold?

Comment: U can see what i mean by the spike on the first picture. This is the spike. I can provide gigabytes of data if needed right now i'm more focused on getting the result at least on one provided graph.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, PaoloJ42! I've read the info from links you provided but is there any way I can get NN to just straightforward return 0 or 1, so essentially  use it to define by itself if that's a spike or not?

Comment: @AlterEGO Could you supply a sample of the original xy and spike data as a file? My understanding is that you want to supply both x-axis and y-axis values, and the net returns the x location for which it finds a spike. However, the code seems to take in 64 features and provide a single output, so it's not clear to me how the data is being supplied to the net. The samples are shaped 64 x 2 - is that 64 timesteps for x and y? And they correspond to a 1x2 output that is [x location, spike/not spike].

Comment: @MuhammedYunus yes, you're correct.

Comment: @AlterEGO If some of the blue data and red data could be supplied as a file (enough for a bit of model training), it would enable me to explore the data a bit more.

Comment: @MuhammedYunus added file link into the question

Comment: `x_y_res.csv` has 2 rows: top row is the x coordinate, and bottom is spike size. It has one column for each train segment of 64. `x_y_train.csv` is the blue curve (top row is x coordinate, bottom row is y coordinate). An issue with `x_y_res` is that **everything is 0** except two entries - we'd need more spike data. In your figure there are lots of red lines, but `x_y_res` only has two non-zero values - is that a mistake?

Comment: @MuhammedYunus Not a mistake everything should be 0 except 2 values  since there are 2 spikes on graph. Red bars is what NN predicted to be spikes.

Comment: I see. I think two positive values is too little to train a net, so I can't really experiment with that.

Answer (score 1):

Basic attempt at detecting the edges using signal processing.

Original data:
[image]

I smoothed the data and took its gradient. Locations where the gradient size exceeded a threshold were used to filter out spike locations. The locations were noisy so I merged similar values together to get the final spike locations (orange):

[image]

Load data and plot: Note that I first reformatted your CSVs into a 2-column format (`x_y_res.csv` was formatted into `x` and `spike` columns, and `x_y_train.csv` was formatted into `x` and `y` columns).

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

res = pd.read_csv('/mnt/c/dev/x_y_res2.csv')
res

trn = pd.read_csv('/mnt/c/dev/x_y_train2.csv')
trn

for i in range(2):
    plt.plot(trn.x, trn.y, label='data')
    plt.scatter(res.x, res.spike, color='tab:red', label='spike size')
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(8, 2.5)
    plt.gcf().legend(ncols=2)
    plt.gca().set(xlabel='x', ylabel='y')
    if i == 1: plt.xlim(0.04, 0.18)
    plt.show()
```

Spike detection and plotting:

```
data_smoothing = 15     #must be >=1 (1: no smoothing)
gradient_smoothing = 1  #must be >=1 (1: no smoothing)
spike_detection_frac = 0.2 #>20% of max gradient = spike is detected
slope_max_duration = 10e-4 #used for grouping noisy slope events together

trn_y_smooth = pd.Series(trn.y).rolling(data_smoothing).mean()
tnr_y_smooth = np.ma.masked_invalid(trn_y_smooth)

grad = np.gradient(trn_y_smooth, trn.x)
grad = pd.Series(grad).rolling(gradient_smoothing).agg(lambda vals: vals.mean())
grad = np.ma.masked_invalid(grad)

plt.plot(trn.x, trn.y, lw=5, color='gray', label='raw y')
plt.plot(trn.x, trn_y_smooth, lw=1, color='lightgray', label=f'y (smooth: {data_smoothing})')
plt.scatter(res.x, res.spike, color='green', label='spike amplitude', marker='v', s=200, zorder=3)

plt.ylabel('y')
plt.ylim(-0.1, 1.1)
plt.xlim(0.04, 0.18)

#Plot gradient and detected spikes
plt.gca().twinx().scatter(
    trn.x, grad, color='magenta', marker='_', lw=2.5,
    label=f'gradient (smooth: {gradient_smoothing})', s=50
)

#Filter out gradients that cross the detection threshold
large_grad_bool = np.abs(grad) > np.abs(grad).max() * spike_detection_frac
x_locations_noisy = trn.x.values[large_grad_bool]

bin_edges = np.arange(x_locations_noisy.min() * 0.95,
                      x_locations_noisy.max() * 1.05,
                      step=slope_max_duration)
counts, bins = np.histogram(x_locations_noisy, bins=bin_edges)
x_locations_clean = bins[:-1][counts > 1]

#Plot locations of detected spikes
for x_loc in x_locations_clean:
    plt.gca().axvline(
        x=x_loc, color='tab:orange',
        lw=15, alpha=0.25,
        label=('' if x_loc==x_locations_clean[0] else '_') +  f'detected spikes (n={len(x_locations_clean)})'
    )
plt.ylabel('gradient')

plt.gcf().legend(ncols=5, bbox_to_anchor=(0.85, 0.95))
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10, 5)
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but to me it's important to solve this problem using NN. Your solution isn't using one, yet it looks quite good!

Comment: Thanks. The sample data only contains 2 spikes, which is not enough for me to experiment with. If the sample data contained at least a few hundred spikes, that would be more realistic for exploring neural net options.

Comment: I understand. Yet that is what I'm trying to achieve. I think I can train NN with handmade data with hundreds of spikes, but it probably won't be affective at spotting just 2 for example. This is the real example of data on which the NN would've been used to identify spikes, so I use it as a training sample.

Comment: I see. I think what you propose sounds like a good *test* for a trained net to see if it performs well on the 2 realistic cases you provided. Before being tested though, it needs to be trained, and the training part requires a lot more spike examples for the net to learn from.